# Is it possible using confusion matrix with multiple results?

Tags: python, confusion-matrix

label of test data (`y_true`) allowed **OR** logic.

```
C = "Cat"
H = "Hen"
A = "Ant" 

y_true = [C / H, A / H, A, A, C, C, H, H]
y_pred = [C, H, H, A, A, C, C, H, H]

confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
```

Where, if the value of `y_pred` is `C` when the value of `y_true` is `A` or `C`, means it is True Positive (TP).

Comment: your code has syntax issue, `C / H` where `C` and `H` are string, you cannot divide two strings. Do you mean "C or H" when you use   `C / H` ?

Comment: I know. It's just a parable. The focus is only on **Logical OR (||)** y_true (confusion matrix).